# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' when I try to do a pivot from a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

My Python code takes a bank statement from Excel and creates a dataframe that categorises each transaction based on description.

Example code:

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np

dff = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['20221003', '20221005'],
                   'Tran Type': ['BOOK TRANSFER CREDIT', 'ACH DEBIT'],
                   'Debit Amount': [0.00, -220000.00],
                   'Credit Amount': [182.90, 0.0],
                   'Description': ['BOOK TRANSFER CREDIT FROM ACCOUNT 98754877', 'USREF2548 ACH OFFSET'],
                   'Amount': [-220000.00, 182.90]})
```

Then the bit that adds a column that categorises it if certain words appear in the description:

```
import re
dff['Category'] = dff['Description'].str.findall('Ref|BCA|Fund|Transfer', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

Output:
[What it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bilsH.png)

But this code will not work. Any ideas why?

```
pivotf = dff
pivotf = pd.pivot_table(pivotf, 
index=["Date"], columns="Category",
values=['Amount'],
margins=False, margins_name="Total")
```

The error message is TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

When I change columns from "Category" to anything else, it works fine. I have tried converting the column from object to string but this doesn't actually convert it.

Comment: Can you have more than one `'Ref|BCA|Fund|Transfer'` per row/description?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [explode()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) function:

```
dff['Category'] = dff['Description'].str.findall('Ref|BCA|Fund|Transfer', flags=re.IGNORECASE).explode()
print(dff)
```

Returning:

```
       Date             Tran Type  ...    Amount  Category
0  20221003  BOOK TRANSFER CREDIT  ... -220000.0  TRANSFER
1  20221005             ACH DEBIT  ...     182.9       REF
```

If Category column has multiple values you have to use it like this:

```
dff['Category'] = dff['Description'].str.findall('Ref|BCA|Fund|Transfer', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
dff=dff.explode('Category')
```

Comment: If it contains a single element (only case where exploding after findall would be viable, then I would recommend using something more efficient rather than explode. +1

Comment: Huge help! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is because the output of [findall()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) is a list:

> Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings or tuples

Which is not a valid type when using pivot_table(). Add `str[0]` at the end if you expect to only have one find per Description/row and it should work:

```
dff['Category'] = dff['Description'].str.findall('Ref|BCA|Fund|Transfer', flags=re.IGNORECASE).str[0]
```

However, it may be more efficient under this scenario, to use [search()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) which would be the perfect fit for this case:

```
dff['Category'] = dff['Description'].str.search('Ref|BCA|Fund|Transfer', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

Regardless of the approach, you will get as final output:

```
         Amount          
Category    REF  TRANSFER
Date                     
20221003    NaN -220000.0
20221005  182.9       NaN
```

Otherwise, you can use explode() as @Clenage suggests but, as shown here, it would lead to a potential issue of duplicated values because of different Categories:

```
pivotf = pd.pivot_table(pivotf.explode('Category'), index=["Date"], columns="Category",values=['Amount'],
margins=False, margins_name="Total")
```

Outputting for example:

```
Category       BCA      FUND    REF  TRANSFER
Date                                         
20221003 -220000.0 -220000.0    NaN -220000.0
20221005       NaN       NaN  182.9       NaN
```

In which case, it's untrue that for 2022-10-03 there was a total of -220000 * 3 money movement.

Comment: hi, if **Description** column contains multiple values and if the user want use all values in category column, Wouldn't it be more correct to use the explode function?

Comment: Hello, it would be better, but it would lead to another issue, which I have addressed in the edit, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Normally I wouldn't expect the Category of a transaction to be a Transfer and a Fund at the same time, so it would most likely be a single element. I have asked this as a comment in OPs question just in case.

Comment: yes, that seems very logical.